# How to manage connection string in runtime with windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, runtime, connection-string, windows-authentication

I'm developing an asp.net mvc web application using Entity Framework. The same application is supposed to be deployed in an intranet model for different clients.

My application is getting data from client databases who have exactly the same structure but with different data for each client, this is why i'm obliged to modify connection string in run-time to match the client environment (DB name and Server name). In addition to that my web app uses Windows Authentication to connect to database.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="LK_Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DAL.Model1.csdl|res://*/DAL.Model1.ssdl|res://*/DAL.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=LKSERVER\SQLSERVER2005;initial catalog=LK_2014;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

What I'd like to know is how is it possible to modify connection string in run-time knowing that the user have to type Server name and Database name once the application runs? And, how to integrate Windows Authentication to connect to the Database ?

Comment: why can't you have multiple connection strings and select the one you want to use on runtime and pass on to your dbContext as param.

Comment: Or build the connection string in code, then pass it into the data context. The constructor accepts name or connection string.

Comment: @Shaz i can't define connection strings because it's up to the client to enter BD name and Server Name.

Comment: So you start with the basic page having drop-down list of select Db, user and pass then on controller based this information select the reletive connection string and pass to the dbContext..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this question is in two parts. The comments so far answer the first part (dynamically pass connection string for `DbContext` at runtime).

```
public TheDbContext() : base("the connection string goes here"){}
```

For the second part, you may need to add `<authentication mode="Windows">` in `web.config`. Also, in IIS enable Windows Authentication and disable Anonymous Authentication.

Comment: I'm not looking to use Windows Authentication for the web application itself, but i want to use Windows Authentication to access the database. In other words the current windows user trying to run the webapp have to be granted access to the the SQLSERVER database in order to display information from db properly.

Comment: You must implement Windows Authentication in the web application in order for integrated security to work. You can find more info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/907hb5w9.aspx. `"The Windows identity supplied to the operating system is used for permission checking, such as NTFS file permissions, or for connecting to a database using integrated security"`.

Comment: You're right i have to use windows authentication and identity impersonating to connect SQLSERVER with the current windows user. unfortunately my scenario encountered a double hop issue.. this a link is talking about it [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx)

Comment: @Selim nice find and good read. I guess it is possible, but not without sacrifice.